# Will magnets in headphones damage my laptop in the long run?

Tags: laptop, headphones

Can I put my headphones on my laptop or will it damage it in the long run due to magnets etc. in the headphones? (I have normal nothing fancy headphones but laptop is expensive)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely sure thats answerable to any amoung of certainty. *However* there's a few interesting points of common sense one can use to find an answer.

The primary magnetically affectable component is your hard disk drive. It has a big magnet RIGHT INSIDE IT *and* the case is magnetically shielded. As such, your headphones are unlikely to affect it. The headphones themselves have *very* directional magnetic fields, and I can't really get anything to stick to mine from outside.

There's nothing to worry about.